# How do you build a python application using snapcraft?

Tags: python, compiling, packaging, snap

I'm trying for several hours, I'm getting this :

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-UWeLSq-build/
Command '['/bin/sh', '/tmp/tmpkajulyzd', 'python2',
 '/home/adi/Eclipse-Workspace/cumulus/parts/cumulus/install/usr/bin/pip2',
 'install', '--global-option=build_ext', 
 '--global-option=-I/home/adi/Eclipse-Workspace/cumulus/parts/cumulus/install/usr/include/python2.7',
 '--target', '/home/adi/Eclipse-Workspace/cumulus/parts/cumulus/install/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '.']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I have read the guides, I have looked at examples the only example with python beeing a small script with no need of dependencies.

Edit, content of the yaml:

```
name: cumulus
version: "1.0.0"
summary: Test summary
description: Test description
confinement: devmode

apps:
  cumulus:
    command: python2 cumulus

parts:
  cumulus:
    plugin: python2
    source: https://github.com/kd8bny/cumulus.git
    source-type: git
```

Comment: Can you post your `snapcraft.yaml` file somewhere?

Comment: Hi and thanks,  I updated my question with the content of the yaml file. as you can see it's the basic example.

Comment: You need to add `stage-packages: [python-distutils-extra]`, but then it fails with this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/21116440/

Comment: :|     python2: can't open file '/home/adi/Desktop/cumulus/parts/cumulus/install/usr/bin/pip2': [Errno 2] No such file or directory  plus same error like last time.

Comment: Maybe try to run `snapcraft clean` before and try again?

Comment: Hey man, just wanted you to know that the error was caused by existence of another version of pip which I installed using pip install -U pip setuptools command, now I got the same error as you.  Thanks

Comment: Does https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen/tree/master/hellomako demonstrate what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I had two versions of `pip`:

- One installed using `sudo apt-get python-pip`
- One installed using `pip install -U pip setuptools`

Apparently `snapcraft` doesn't know from where to copy it when the second command is used to install another version of pip.